# When do Keras activation function get called?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, layer, activation

**Assumption:**

From what I have read, the Keras Dense layer implements the operation ([Keras docs](https://keras.io/layers/core/)):

> output = activation(dot(input, kernel) + bias)

I assume then that every time the predict() method is called, it should trigger the activation function to run. This does not seem to be the case.

**Experiment**:

To test this I have written 2 different implementations of Keras custom activation functions, which should print to screen when the activation function is run. I have specifically updated the call() function because:

> The **call** method defines the computations performed on the input. The
>   function accepts the input tensor as its argument and returns the
>   output tensor after applying the required operations. [reference](https://www.saama.com/blog/deep-learning-diaries-building-custom-layers-in-keras/)

Code:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer, Dense, Dropout, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.activations import sigmoid
from tensorflow.keras.utils import get_custom_objects
import numpy as np

# ====================================================

# Custom Activation layer
class CustomAct(Layer):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomAct, self).__init__()

    def call(self, x):
        print ("  >> CustomAct > call()")
        return sigmoid(x)

# ====================================================

def custom_activation(x):
    print ("  >> custom_activation()")
    return sigmoid(x)

# ====================================================

print ("\nInit Datasets:")
X = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])
y = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]])

# ====================================================

print ("\nBuild:")
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=2))
model.add(Activation(custom_activation))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(CustomAct())

# ====================================================

print ("\nCompile:")
opt = Adam(lr=0.1)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt)

# ====================================================

print ("\nFit:")
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=1, epochs=10, verbose=0)

# ====================================================

print ("\nEvaluate:")
model.evaluate(X, y, verbose=0)

# ====================================================

print ("\nPredict X[0]:")
output = model.predict(X[0:1])
print (output)

print ("\nPredict X[1]:")
output = model.predict(X[1:2])
print (output)

print ("\nPredict X[2]:")
output = model.predict(X[2:3])
print (output)

print ("\nPredict X[3]:")
output = model.predict(X[3:4])
print (output)
```

**Results:**

The output of this is as follows:

```
Init Datasets:

Build:
  >> custom_activation()
  >> CustomAct > call()

Compile:

Fit:
  >> custom_activation()
  >> CustomAct > call()
  >> custom_activation()
  >> CustomAct > call()

Evaluate:
  >> custom_activation()
  >> CustomAct > call()

Predict X[0]:
  >> custom_activation()
  >> CustomAct > call()
[[0.4644116]]

Predict X[1]:
[[0.48512048]]

Predict X[2]:
[[0.46812934]]

Predict X[3]:
[[0.4797536]]
```

**Expectations:**

This was not what I was expecting. I was expecting to see the `>> custom_activation()` code printed every time I ran a prediction. For example:

```
Predict X[0]:
  >> custom_activation()  # Actual output
  >> CustomAct > call()   # Actual output
[[0.4644116]]

Predict X[1]:
  >> custom_activation()  # Expected to see this
  >> CustomAct > call()   # Expected to see this
[[0.48512048]]

Predict X[2]:
  >> custom_activation()  # Expected to see this
  >> CustomAct > call()   # Expected to see this
[[0.46812934]]

Predict X[3]:
  >> custom_activation()  # Expected to see this
  >> CustomAct > call()   # Expected to see this
[[0.4797536]]
```

**Workaround:**

If I change from `model.predict(X[0:1])` to `model().numpy(X[0:1])`, then the activation function is called every time:

Code:

```
print ("\nPredict X[0]:")
output = model(X[0:1]).numpy()     # Updated line
print (output)

print ("\nPredict X[1]:")
output = model(X[1:2]).numpy()     # Updated line
print (output)

print ("\nPredict X[2]:")
output = model(X[2:3]).numpy()     # Updated line
print (output)

print ("\nPredict X[3]:")
output = model(X[3:4]).numpy()     # Updated line
print (output)
```

Output:

```
Predict X[0]:
  >> custom_activation()
  >> CustomAct > call()
[[0.02330273]]

Predict X[1]:
  >> custom_activation()
  >> CustomAct > call()
[[0.91676223]]

Predict X[2]:
  >> custom_activation()
  >> CustomAct > call()
[[0.9246548]]

Predict X[3]:
  >> custom_activation()
  >> CustomAct > call()
[[0.12687866]]
```

**Question:**

Why is the activation function not called every time I call `model.predict()` with a new input value?

Comment: I appreciate the effort put into this question :)